# What are the 'Public Account Liabilities' of the Government of India?

Tags: government-debt, debt, public-economics, government, government-spending

In the [Quarterly Report](https://dea.gov.in/sites/default/files/Quarterly%20Report%20on%20Public%20Debt%20Management%20for%20the%20Quarter%20Jul%20-%20Sep%202020.pdf) on Public Debt Management for the Quarter Jul - Sep 2020 of the Government of India, an increase in 'Public Debt Liabilities' is declared.

What are they?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Factly](https://factly.in/explainer-understanding-government-debt/):

> Public Account liabilities
> include liabilities on account of National Small Saving Fund (NSSF),
> Provident Funds, Reserve Funds and Deposits, and Other Accounts.
> Liabilities under ‘Other Accounts’ include, among others, special
> bonds issued to oil marketing companies, fertilizer companies and
> FCI.